# Does Dart 2.0 have extension methods?

Tags: dart, extension-methods

in dart 2.0,types are mandatory,will dart 2.0 or 2.x add extension methods like

```
static int WordCount(this String str){
   // custom String method here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there won't be extension methods in 2.0.

There is a lot of work going on to be able to move faster after 2.0.
I think extension methods is a popular wish, but there is no definitive statement Dart will get them.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

As of today, Dart 2.6, added extension methods support.